# Less extreme values when reprojecting raster data

Tags: r, raster, map-projections

I am trying to reproject a global raster of artificial light emissions from longitude/latitude to Behrmanns equal area (EPSG:6933) at a resolution of 0.0417 degrees. Due to spikes in data around urban areas when the pixels are interpolated during reprojection, there is c.15% loss of data across the layer.

I have tried converting the raster to a spatial points dataframe, reprojecting the spatial points dataframe and then rasterising using a raster created using the 'projectraster' function as the template raster (I think the dimensions, extent and resolution of the template raster might be the issue?) However, this produces a raster with horizontal lines through the layer.

Here is some example code with Spain as an example. I can email the tif file for Spain (246kb):

```
library("sf")
library("raster")

behrmann <- CRS('+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')

r <- raster("~/Documents/R spatial data[enter image description here][1]/Spain.tif")
cellStats(r, sum) # check summed light emissions
r_temp <- projectRaster(r, crs = behrmann) # creates template for rasterisation (data is lost due to interpolation of data spikes)
spdf <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial = TRUE)
spdf2 <- spTransform(spdf, CRS = behrmann)
r2 <- rasterize(spdf2, r_temp, field = "Spain", fun = "sum")
cellStats(r2, sum) # check no data has been lost
plot(log10(r2)) # see attached image[enter image description here][1]
```

How is it possible to reproject to an equal area without losing data and avoiding the horizontal lines? I have also tried converting to a spatial polygons dataframe instead of the spatial points and this does not produce the lines but instead loses data similar to the 'projectRaster' function. This must be a common(ish) problem but I can't find any help online.

Many thanks in advance.

[Example of horizontal lines after reprojecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX8CQ.png)stack.imgur.com/IV0fZ.png

Answer (score 0):

When transforming a raster, new cell values are computed. This is normally done by averaging, and that leads to less extreme values.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(res=5)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- focal(r, w=matrix(1, 3, 3))
r <- focal(r, w=matrix(1, 3, 3))
r <- round(focal(r, w=matrix(1, 3, 3)))
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 36, 72, 2592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 5, 5  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 229, 473  (min, max)


behrmann <- "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m"
x <- projectRaster(r, crs=behrmann)
x
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 27, 78, 2106  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 482000, 638000  (x, y)
#extent     : -18813530, 18782470, -8607770, 8618230  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 233.0725, 471.7214  (min, max)
```

However, you could use the nearest neighbor method instead (that would be similar to what you attempted by transforming point data).

```
z <- projectRaster(r, crs=behrmann, method="ngb")
z
#class      : RasterLayer 
# ...
#values     : 229, 473  (min, max)
```

or indeed use polygons (if you do not have too many cells)

```
p <- as(r, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
y <- spTransform(p, behrmann)

y
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 2160 
#extent      : -17367530, 17367530, -7089914, 7089914  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#variables   : 1
#names       : layer 
#min values  :   229 
#max values  :   473
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response. Unfortunately, I have already tried the nearest neighbour approach, with much the same result (lost data). I think that with artificial light at night data, or human population data for that matter, the spikes in urban areas are too extreme and so data is lost.   No data is lost with the spatial points approach, but you end up with these horizontal lines on the raster. Using the spatial polygons approach ended up with lost data, it also took over a day to run on a global raster at 0.0417 degree resolution